# VB.Net Different on Other Machine

Tags: vb.net

This has been driving me nuts for days now. Down the cost of a couple of servers to say nothing of the hit to my sanity.. I've narrowed down the point of the problem but I've no idea the reason.

My script pulls data from different websites and compares them. It works locally and on my laptop (Both Windows 7 ultimate) but on various different systems (mostly virtual) and several different version of Windows - it's not working the same way. Tool loads as normal, browser loads the same data but just seems to get bored of using it.

It reads the same way. I can dump it in a msgbox the same way. It won't write to an array or listbox the way it does locally.

So this is where it goes wrong.

Because the data is not always there I use a stringsplit:

```
Dim parts As String() = readertest.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine},
                                               StringSplitOptions.None)
```

I've ran through the different systems dumping the output to make sure that Environment.NewLine isn't differnet and everything reads fine and is in the same order.

Right after that is where the difference starts:

To deal with the fact the data isn't always there I count the size of the parts array.

```
If parts.Count = 13 Then 'Full box.
firstdata = parts(5)
seconddata = parts(6)
```

parts.count comes back as 13.
parts(5) and parts(6) both read out as the same value. That would be normal. That's what you'd expect.

But inside that If parts.count = 13 it writes that data into an array and a list box. Works fine locally. This is where it falls apart on the server.

Why on earth would this be different?

/Edit:

After the whole read I just dumped the array. Data is there. Why is data in the array. Writing to the array works and for some reason the other systems won't show it entering a listbox?

The other list boxes work with different data.

Comment: You seem to be saying that a statement that you haven't included in you post is doing something different on different systems, but you don't say what it actually does on either system, or what the data is. You must think our crystal balls are really good!

Comment: Is it possble that you have different regional settings on the other servers that is affecting the string processing in your code?

Comment: It's not really a duplicate Lars I've tried to narrow it down since then.

Comment: Blackwood I haven't really missed any code out. The code I've posted which seems pretty straightforward is doing different things. Ceres that sounds like a reasonable question but I don't know what kind of regional settings that would be.

Comment: @MaxBetter: You haven't posted the code that adds data to the ListBox (which you say is what is failing), and you haven't posted the data that fails. It would also help if you identify what is different about the systems where the code doesn't do what you want compared to those where it does do what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to [ceres](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409762/ceres) for suggesting it.

The answer was the regional settings on the servers. They're set to US while my local systems are UK.

There was no comparison or anything going on which would make encoding an issue so I've no earthly idea why it worked but it's running properly on all servers now.